# How do I read this this sigma notation?

Tags: summation

I think this means the fraction of all true occurrences, where y-hat and y are equal, but I am unfamiliar with the last term.  Can someone give the proper terminology to describe this and a reference for learning more advanced sigma notations?

[image: accuracy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf 1(\hat{y_i}=y_i)$ is an **indicator function**; a piecewise function that has a value of 1 when the argument, $\hat{y_i}=y_i$, is true, and a value of 0 when it is false.

$$\mathbf 1(\hat{y_i}=y_i)~=~\begin{cases} 1 &:&\hat{y_i}=y_i\\[1ex]0&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you very much.  Without a math background, I'm unsure how I would learn this.  Do you know of references for learning things like indicator functions?